# PHP function call inside if statment executed no matter what

Tags: php

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
header('Content-Type: application/json, charset=utf-8');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods:  POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');


//... some require statements

if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
    $ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
}else if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
    $ip_address = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}else{
    $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

    
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$hash= $_POST['hash'];
$logger = new logger();
$urlLength = strlen($hash);

//this is where the problem occurs
if( $urlLength < 23){
    echo json_encode([
        "error"=>"error"            
    ]);  

    // this line is always executed even if the if clause isn't met
    $logger->add_log($ip_address);    
    die();
}
?>
```

Some strange behavior is happening. No matter what `$logger->add_log($ip_address);` will be executed (even if the `strlen` is greater than 23) but not any of the other code inside the if statement. When the if statement clause is met correctly the other code is executed correctly. The problem is `$logger->add_log($ip_address);` is executed no matter what. Why is this happening? This is on an NGINX server using php-fpm if that matters.

the class looks like this:

```
<?php
class logger{
    
    
    public function __construct() { 
    }

    public function add_log($ip_address){

        // some code that adds to log and returns boolean

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Log `$urlLength` right before the `if` condition. You can see whats happening then,

Comment: before `if` fo `var_dump($urlLength);` and show us what you got?

Comment: @Chin.Udara @WM-SH-PD-TV-FC I just double checked and the output of `$urlLength` is accurate. It's the length of the string as an int. The `die()` statement and the `echo` don't get executed but only the function call is

Comment: Can you change the json_encode line like this. **echo json_encode(array("error"=>"error"));**. I am not sure whether your sentence is right here.

Comment: @dspillai `array()` and `[]` function the same way. When the if statement clause is met everything inside it gets executed correctly. When it is not the function call `$logger->add_log($ip_address);` and only this function call gets executed anyway.

Comment: @1000iq if the `die()` and `echo` aren't executed but the `$logger->add_log()` is, then it stands to reason that it is not the code in your `if` statement that is executing at all. I would assume that you have another `$logger->add_log()` call somewhere else

Comment: Try adding [`debug_print_backtrace();`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.debug-print-backtrace.php) to your `add_log()` method so you can see where calls are coming from

Comment: @Phil I have confirmed it is coming from that line of code inside the if statement

Comment: @1000iq Thank you, this is a piece of new knowledge.

Comment: Ah, you appear to be posting via JS and it seems you require CORS. Could it be you're handling 2 requests; the pre-flight `OPTIONS` and then the `POST`?

Comment: @Phil I tried by removing `OPTIONS` but I still get the same result

Comment: I think you misunderstood. When a pre-flight request is required (which it typically is when posting JSON), there are two separate requests made

Comment: @Phil My JS request code looks like this
`this.httpClient.post<any>(URL,{hash}).subscribe( data => { // ...code });`

Comment: @Phil It makes sense that that's what's happening but how can I fix it?

Comment: @Phil Ok it's working good now. I added this `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
exit(0);
}` Thank you very much. You can add that as the answer and I will up-vote it